# Function call always as last function call in current Block

Tags: solidity, blockchain, poa

I'm implementing a DoubleAuction and I want to call the breakEven function, that finds the market clearing price, always as very last function in the current Block.
Is there any way that I can check in solidity if the current transaction is the last transaction in the current block and if so, I'd call the breakEven function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no good way to get this sort of information about the current block in Solidity.

An idea that may be more practical is to call the function in the *next* block, and have it find the price for the previous block

Comment: any ideas on how I could make sure that this call would be the very first function call in the next block then?

Comment: You can keep track of the last time the function was called, and require that it has not been called yet on this block